# Embedding Python to C++ Receiving Error Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: python, c++, linux, embedding

This is my first go at Embedding Python in C++.

I am just trying to create a simple program so I understand how it works.

The following is my code.

main.cpp

```
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include </usr/include/python3.8/Python.h>
#include <iostream>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    
    PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pFunc, *pArgs, *pValue;

    Py_Initialize();


    pName = PyUnicode_FromString((char*)"script");
    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
    pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, (char*)"test");
    pArgs = PyTuple_Pack(1, PyUnicode_FromString((char*)"Greg"));
    pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);
    
    auto result = _PyUnicode_AsString(pValue);
    std::cout << result << std::endl;

    Py_Finalize();

      

}
```

script.py

```
def test(person):
    return "What's up " + person;
```

This is how I have been compiling on Linux

```
g++ -I/usr/include/python3.8/ main.cpp -L/usr/lib/python3.8/config-3.8-x86_64-linux-gnu -lpython3.8 -o output
```

I am compiling like this because (#include <Python.h> has been giving me troubles, Yes I have tried sudo apt-get install python3.8-dev)

The file compiles successfully but when I try to run ./output I receive the following error.

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I searched up what this error means and it is saying that Segmentation fault is a specific kind of error caused by accessing memory that “does not belong to you.”

But which memory does not belong to me? Is it the python file?

Any Guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Segfault can happen for any number of reasons. It is undefined behaviour if python tries to modify a string literal, so never cast `const` away from them. You could try to debug the c++ program and see what exactly causes it.

Comment: This would be a great time to learn how to use a debugger (such as gdb); but you can always start with so called `printf debugging`.  Stick a print statement between each statement to see where it dies.  However, gdb is way more powerful.

Comment: Also, check your returns. Any of these could return NULL because something was not as you expected.

Comment: I put print statements after each line and it fails when
  
```pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, (char*)"test");
```
is called.

Comment: Great, and what is pModule at that point?

Comment: @scriptKiddie123 So you didn't check if `pModule` is `NULL` after the call `pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);`?

Comment: Hint: `if (variable == NULL)` and the API function `PyErr_Print()` will be your friends to figure out what went wrong.

Comment: I wrote this code right after ```pModule = PyImport_Import(pName)```

if(pModule){
        std::cout << "True"<<std::endl;
    } else{
        std::cout <<"False"<<std::endl; 
    }

It returned False, meaning pModule is Null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After each and every one of those statements, you will need to check for errors, using something of the form:

```
if (varname == NULL) {
    cout << “An error occured” << endl;
    PyErr_Print();
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
 }
```

This will check if the python layer through an error; and if so will ask it to print the Python traceback to the screen, and exit. You can use this traceback to figure out what your error is.

Any of those functions can fail, and you need to check for failure before you continue. Using the Python C API is extremely fiddly because of this. Most C API functions that return a pointer return NULL on error, and passing NULL into any function without checking it first is bound to result in a crash.

You get a segmentation fault from accessing a NULL pointer, as nearly all modern systems map access of NULL to a segmentation fault or crash of some sort to catch programming errors.

Comment: Also, don’t cast the strings to (char *).  They should already be (const char *) which is what the Python API expects in most places.

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'script'. I must be assigning pName incorrectly.

Comment: It means it can’t find your script.py.  Your pName is fine, since it printed out the name `script`.  You will have to figure out where it wants your script.py to be.  As far as I can tell, it uses `sys.path` exactly like using Python.

Comment: They are both in the same directory. Are you implying this may be a path issue?

Comment: And if you run “python3.8” in the same directory as the executable you generated, does `import script` work?

Comment: ```PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");```
```PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append(\".\")");```

This did the job